# Sort Map based on ordering defined in ENUM

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Map<String, Id>` and i want to sort them based on ENUM with sort order..

```
Map values: Apple, 1
            Banana, 2
            Grapes, 3
            Coconut, 4
            Mango, 5
            Avocado, 6
```

my ENUM compose of

```
FruitName(sortOrder, id)
```

What is the best way to do the sorting?

Comment: So use a `TreeMap` with a `Comparator`, assuming the `String` key is a fruit name. --- Or are you asking about sorting by value? If so: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109383/5221149)

Comment: but how can i apply the enum? and there are scenario that Mango is not in the enum order.. so it will just put to last..

Comment: You didn't say that new rule in the question. Please **edit** the question and add relevant information. --- Are you asking how to find enum constant `FruitName.Banana` from the string value `"Banana"`? If so, call `FruitName.valueOf("Banana")`

Comment: no we will find it by ID.

Comment: So sort map by value. Then see the link I gave.

Comment: Use your enum objects as the key to your map rather than strings. Use `EnumMap` Implementation of `Map`. That implementation maintains an iteration order based on the order in which the enum objects were named in the enum.  `Map< Fruit , Id > = new EnumMap<>() ;`

Comment: the design is already there.. they uses String..